# Error in Making Executable Jar file using Maven

Tags: java, maven, logging

This is my `pom.xml` file of the application

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smart.data.manipulator</groupId>
    <artifactId>SmartDataManipulator</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SmartDataManipulator</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency for Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency for MySQL JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SmartDataManipulator</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Make this jar executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                            <mainClass>com.smart.data.manipulator.Starter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Copy project dependency -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have setup all the required stuff to make my jar file executable.

Following is the error I get once I run the `mvn package` command on the terminal. I use **Ubuntu** as my OS and **IdeaJ** as my IDE.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.smart.data.manipulator.Starter.<clinit>(Starter.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

I know that this exception indicates that Log4J dependency is not existing. But It is there in the dependency folder.

```
junit-3.8.1.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your MANIFEST.MF file does not tell the JVM where to look for libraries, and that is why you get the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. This is because there is no ClassPath section inside the manifest.

The goals of the [MANIFEST.MF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file is to store the fully classified name of the main class and the location to all the libraries needed to make the application work.

In a Maven project, this file is typically generated by the `maven-jar-plugin`. You need to configure the `maven-jar-plugin` this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                <mainClass>com.smart.data.manipulator.Starter</mainClass>
                <!-- Adds a ClassPath section to the manifest -->                    
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <!-- All the dependencies are stored inside the dependency folder, as created by default by the maven-dependency-plugin -->
                <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix> 
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi .. It was able to over that exception .. ^_^ but still I get this error :

Error: Could not find or load main class jar